# Can i use the same code generated by inspector recorder in Android and IOS app?

Tags: java, android, ios, automation, appium

I'm trying to automate my test cases using appium inspector recorder, for the same application developed in Android and IOS. Can i use the same generated code to write my script?

The location of each element by xpath for example is it unique or there is a way  for the same application element location are the same for both Android and IOS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath won't be same on both platforms. You can use other locators like Name, Id and class name to make it work on both platforms.